# Several identical tags allowed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, editor

Look at the screenshot below:

[image: Multiple identical tags]

Should that be possible? I don't think you should be able to select the same tag over, and **over**, and ***over***. It doesn't stop at five. Or ten. Or fifty.

It works correctly server-side; the duplicates are all removed. There are no error messages, however.

Comment: Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2jZAq.png

Comment: "It works correctly server-side; the duplicates are all removed." This sounds like `status-bydesign` then. I suppose there's an edge case where you might intend to add two nearly identical tags, type one tag twice, and the duplicate is removed. Can you think of any tags that would be susceptible to that?

Comment: @Mysticial: I fear that is the most common idea on all crappy user interfaces out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated the tag editor so that it prevents the user from entering duplicate tags. It now also hides already present tags from the auto-completion box, so the user is not tempted into selecting a tag more than once. This tweak is rolling out with build `2014.3.17.2063` on meta and `214.3.17.1465` on sites.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, it has to be server-side validated no matter what. So rather than waste time and, more importantly, bandwidth adding in client-side checks for silly things like this, just ignore it client-side and let the server take care of it upon submission.

A user knows that adding a tag to a question multiple times doesn't make any sense and should expect them to be collapsed into one instance, so an error message is useless. Kind of like feeding a troll - no one would have a legitimate reason for wanting the same tag multiple times.

This same logic is applied to the favorite/ignored tags filters. You can enter non-existent tags, tags that exceed maximum length, whatever. But who cares? It doesn't break anything, and validating some of these is just a waste of resources better used on more serious things.

Comment: "A user knows that adding a tag to a question multiple times doesn't make any sense..." - I always assume the user doesn't know anything. I guide them with the design. Think of the door that pushes open but has a pull handle... At the same time, I do agree that it is a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: Who says you need to send a request to validate? Just check that the tag isn't already in the box before formatting it as `span.post-tag`.

Comment: @Mooseman That still requires additional code that takes up more space in the JS and eats up extra bandwidth that doesn't need eaten.

Comment: @animuson `var match = false; $(".post-tag").each(if($(this).text() === newTagName){match = true; return false; /*Break the each loop*/}); if(match === true){alert('The tag has already been added.');}else{/*Add the tag*/alert('Adding tag...');}` Selectors have to be more specific, but since jQuery is already being used, that's all you need.

Comment: @Mooseman The whole idea of minimizing JS for performance is to *use as few characters as possible*. In my opinion, that block of code you just provided is *way* too much of an addition for something as silly as duplicated tags. You're adding to the size of the global JS file that gets downloaded by every single visitor for something that isn't really an issue. *Why does it matter if a user enters duplicate tags?* It really doesn't. They get stripped upon submission and life goes on.